# Google indexing 20 000 url and more

Tags: sitemap

do hoy know how long it takes to google to index a website with over 20 000 url? So far, it takes ages.
Sitemap is working properly no error from console 
Any tip to speed up the process, any good idea o things we have to do?
We are creating  a very large site with thousands of url but if google takes that long we will die b4 we get indexed by Google.
Many thanks for your help 
Have a great day

Comment: Thank you guys, the Sitemap was created 1 month ago but we still struggeling . We only get around 300 pages per lots

Answer (score 1):

**When did you post the sitemap on the search console?** 
If that was like yesterday, give it a bit more time.

**How do you check if the pages are indexed?**
If you check by looking at your traffic, you're going to have a bad time. Indexing pages does not mean you will get traffic. The best way to check your indexing is by searching on Google the following  "site:yourdomain.com". The number of results is in theory the number of pages indexed by Google.

**How unique are your pages?**
If your pages are not unique enough, Google will skip some of them to prevent duplicate content in their index. In other words, having 20,000 pages in your sitemap does not necessary means 20k pages indexed on Google.